Why XQuartz lists 64 visuals when configured for Millions of colors?
I have the following Xlib program:
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Display *display;
    XVisualInfo vinfo_template = {0};
    XVisualInfo *vinfo;
    int n, screen;

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (display == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open X display\n");
        return 1;
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(display);

    // Use an empty template to get all available visuals
    vinfo_template.screen = screen;
    vinfo = XGetVisualInfo(display, VisualScreenMask, &vinfo_template, &n);

    if (vinfo != NULL) {
        printf("Available visuals:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Visual %d: Class: %d, Depth: %d\n", i,
                   vinfo[i].class, vinfo[i].depth);
        }
        XFree(vinfo);
    } else {
        printf("No visuals found\n");
    }

    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}

When I run this program against a XQuartz X server configured to support millions of colors I get the following output:
$ ./list_visuals
Available visuals:
Visual 0: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 1: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 2: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 3: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 4: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 5: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 6: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 7: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 8: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 9: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 10: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 11: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 12: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 13: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 14: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 15: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 16: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 17: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 18: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 19: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 20: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 21: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 22: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 23: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 24: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 25: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 26: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 27: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 28: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 29: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 30: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 31: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 32: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 33: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 34: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 35: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 36: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 37: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 38: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 39: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 40: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 41: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 42: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 43: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 44: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 45: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 46: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 47: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 48: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 49: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 50: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 51: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 52: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 53: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 54: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 55: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 56: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 57: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 58: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 59: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 60: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 61: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 62: Class: 4, Depth: 24
Visual 63: Class: 4, Depth: 24

Since class 4 is TrueColor class,

why do we have 64 different visuals?
shouldn't we have just one since TrueColor is read/only and therefore all visuals will be the same?

Note: the client runs in FreeBSD and the variable DISPLAY is exported to a MacOS running XQuartz X server.

This question has been flagged as similar to:
Why are XVisuals repeated in xdpyinfo
Which is related and relevant.
But in the context of writing a pure X11 application (no GLX), which visual out of the 64 ones listed shall be selected?

vinfo_template was not initialized. What happens if you set it to NULL?

Thanks for the comment @LajosArpad, I have set the values in the struct to zero using XVisualInfo vinfo_template = {0}; then I get exactly the same result. Is that what you were suggesting to test? (I have edited the question to reflect this)

This question is similar to: Why are XVisuals repeated in xdpyinfo. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@G.M. This seems to be the case since a local execution of glxinfo -v shows different combinations of auxBuffers, depthSize, multiSample and multiSampleBuffers (up to 64). glxinfo -v can not executed remotely.
The question referenced states why the visuals are "duplicated" but it does not explain why there are different options and why they translate into different visuals.

Sorry, I don't really understand your last comment.  While all of the visuals might have the same X11 credentials, they all vary in their support for the various OpenGL related attributes.  Perhaps you could update your question with an example that illustrates any remaining confusion/misunderstanding.

Would that mean than from X11 perspective, they will provide the same capabilities?
In the context of writing a X11 application, how do you know which one you shall select?.

Exactly, and you can select any one.  I've just fished out my copy of O'Reilly's 'Xlib Programming Manual' and the example code has visualList = XGetVisualInfo(... followed by some error checking and then proceeds to use visualList[0] for the remaining code.

Thanks. That's the reference book I am following. Said that, I wonder if GLX/OpenGL was taken into consideration at all back in the day when the book was written (OpenGL was released by SGI in 1992 and I do not know if/when GLX was made available outside IRIX at the time the book was written).
